# How to return a 404 in case of a queryset is true for Django DetailView

Tags: django, django-queryset

Having a field inside my model

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    published = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
        help_text="Whether this is visible."
    )
```

My detailView is pretty simple and straight forward so far

```
class myDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = "detail.html"
    model = myModel
```

I'm looking for a way to render a 404-error on corrosponding django.views.generic.DetailView in case of the boolean is False. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the queryset to:

```
class MyDetailView(DetailView):
    model = myModel
    template_name = 'detail.html'
    queryset = myModel.objects.filter(published=True)
```

it will thus only take `myModel` objects into account where `published` is set to `True`. In case a `myModel` object exists with `published=False`, then it will return a 404, since the filtered queryset will not contain that element.